# Change the background color of a div using Javascript and a json file

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to dynamically create and color divs based on a .json file i have created. I have been able to create each individual div but adding the colors from the file is what I can't seem to do, i have been able to print out the color names but being able to change each div is giving me issues any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

My code is below.

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="css/text" href="">
   <title>Json and Ajax</title>
</head>
<style>

    h1
    {
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .boxvalue
    {
        width:150px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 2px solid rgb(199, 91, 91);
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 20px;
    }

    .Colorname
    {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <header>
      <h1>Colors</h1>
    </header>
   <div id="ColorArea">

   </div>
</div>
    <script src="colorequest.js"></script>
 </body>
```

js File

```
var ColorContainer = document.getElementById('ColorArea');

var NewRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
NewRequest.open('GET', 'colors.json', true);

NewRequest.onload = function()
{
    var ColorData = JSON.parse(NewRequest.responseText);
    renderHTML(ColorData);
};
NewRequest.send();

/* Function used to render the Color Data */
function renderHTML(data){
 var ColorInfo = " ";
 var Colordiv 

 for (i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        ColorInfo += data[i].code.hex + " " + data[i].color + "<br>";
        Colordiv = document.createElement('div');
        Colordiv.classList.add('boxvalue');
        ColorContainer.appendChild(Colordiv);
    }

}
```

json File

```
[
    {
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,255,255,1],
        "hex": "#000"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "white",
      "category": "value",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0,0,0,1],
        "hex": "#FFF"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,0,0,1],
        "hex": "#FF0"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "blue",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0,0,255,1],
        "hex": "#00F"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "yellow",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,255,0,1],
        "hex": "#FF0"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "green",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "secondary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0,255,0,1],
        "hex": "#0F0"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background color of the div with CSS:

```
Colordiv.style.backgroundColor = data[i].code.hex;
```

The for loop becomes

```
for (i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
  ColorInfo += data[i].code.hex + " " + data[i].color + "<br>";
  Colordiv = document.createElement('div');
  Colordiv.classList.add('boxvalue');
  Colordiv.style.backgroundColor = data[i].code.hex;
  ColorContainer.appendChild(Colordiv);
}
```

```js
var ColorContainer = document.getElementById('ColorArea');

var ColorData = [
    {
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,255,255,1],
        "hex": "#000"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "white",
      "category": "value",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0,0,0,1],
        "hex": "#FFF"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,0,0,1],
        "hex": "#FF0"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "blue",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0,0,255,1],
        "hex": "#00F"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "yellow",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,255,0,1],
        "hex": "#FF0"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "green",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "secondary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0,255,0,1],
        "hex": "#0F0"
      }
    }
  ]

/* Function used to render the Color Data */
function renderHTML(data){
 var ColorInfo = " ";
 var Colordiv 

 for (i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        ColorInfo += data[i].code.hex + " " + data[i].color + "<br>";
        Colordiv = document.createElement('div');
        Colordiv.classList.add('boxvalue');
        Colordiv.style.backgroundColor = data[i].code.hex;
        ColorContainer.appendChild(Colordiv);
    }

}

renderHTML(ColorData)
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="css/text" href="">
   <title>Json and Ajax</title>
</head>
<style>

    h1
    {
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .boxvalue
    {
        width:150px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 2px solid rgb(199, 91, 91);
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 20px;
    }

    .Colorname
    {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <header>
      <h1>Colors</h1>
    </header>
   <div id="ColorArea">

   </div>
</div>
    <script src="colorequest.js"></script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're really only missing an assignment to your divs' style property, which you can access using `element.style.cssPropertyInCamelCase`. You can access any inline CSS declaration this way, just convert the property name from *kebab-case* to *camelCase* in your JavaScript.

And since your colors JSON is going to be parsed as an array, you can also simplify the loop to a forEach call:

```js
var colors = [{
    "color": "black",
    "category": "hue",
    "type": "primary",
    "code": {
      "rgba": [255, 255, 255, 1],
      "hex": "#000"
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "white",
    "category": "value",
    "code": {
      "rgba": [0, 0, 0, 1],
      "hex": "#FFF"
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "category": "hue",
    "type": "primary",
    "code": {
      "rgba": [255, 0, 0, 1],
      "hex": "#F00"
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "blue",
    "category": "hue",
    "type": "primary",
    "code": {
      "rgba": [0, 0, 255, 1],
      "hex": "#00F"
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "yellow",
    "category": "hue",
    "type": "primary",
    "code": {
      "rgba": [255, 255, 0, 1],
      "hex": "#FF0"
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "green",
    "category": "hue",
    "type": "secondary",
    "code": {
      "rgba": [0, 255, 0, 1],
      "hex": "#0F0"
    }
  }
]

colors.forEach(function(color) {
  var colorDiv = document.createElement('div');
  colorDiv.textContent = color.color + ' ' + color.code.hex;
  colorDiv.style.backgroundColor = color.code.hex;
  document.getElementById('ColorArea').appendChild(colorDiv);
});
```

```css
#ColorArea {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="ColorArea">
</div>
```